# Relationships between two functions that are the functions of the same variable

Tags: calculus

$f$ and $g$ are both the functions of the same variable $x$ (domain) that ranges over $\mathbb{R}$. $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ where $a$ is any value in domain produces a single result for each function.

Now I consider the case of derivative/differentiation $\frac{df}{dg}$. I note that $f$ may not be one-domain-value-one-range function of $g$. In this case, would the use of chain rule and $df/dg$ be OK (to calculate $df/dx$), as implicit differentiation is OK to use?

Edit: So Let's say that we know that $f = \pm 2\sqrt g$. And we know that $f$ and $g$ are the functions of a single variable $x$.

Comment: What is $\dfrac {df}{dg}$?

Comment: differentiation/derivative.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's on the RHS side: $\dfrac {df}{dg}(x)=$$___ ?$

Comment: No, I mean I am asking for a general case.

Comment: You're telling us to consider $\dfrac {df}{dg}$. Please define this symbol.

Comment: I defined and clarified. Would have a look at the edit?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ could fail to be a function on $D\cap g(D)$. In particular, it is still a function on $D$, and if you don't try to extend it somehow, then you're still going to have well-definedness on a subset of the domain. So perhaps it's not injective, but it is still a function.

(To address your edit: I cannot think of a situation where the $\pm$ is warranted, unless $f$ acts according to $+$ on some values in $g$'s range, but $-$ on the others.)

Once you know that, then yes, you can apply the chain rule, just as you suspected. That is, you can simply multiply in the usual way to get $\frac{df}{dx}(a)=\frac{df}{dg}(g(a))\frac{dg}{dx}(a)$.

Now, if $f$ is itself defined implicitly, then you cannot always get away with just parameterizing the derivative based on $a$. But if you are comfortable with implicit differentiation, then you should be familiar with the issues that arise in this case; there are no additional difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is $\frac {df} {dg} = \frac {df} {dx} \cdot \frac {dx} {dg} = \frac {df} {dx} \cdot (\frac {dg} {dx})^{-1}$ if I understand your question correctly.  Watch out for divide by zero issues though.